# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am sending an ajax request and I have given route to it but it still says not found.

This is what I am doing

web.php

`Route::post('/check_username/{username}', RegisterController@check_user_username');`

RegisterController.php

```
public function check_user_username($username)
{
    $uername = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($username))))));
    $user = new User;
    $user = $user->where(['username','LIKE',$username])->get();

    return $user;
}
```

ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#username").blur(function(){
    //$(this).css("background-color", "red");
    var username = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/check_username/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {"username":username},
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

What is wrong and what is left to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route should look like this:

```
Route::post('check_username', RegisterController@check_user_username');
```

And method:

```
public function check_user_username(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('username', 'like', '%'.$request->username.'%')->first();
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

Comment: Might like to add someting about `return $user;` needs to be `echo $user;`

Comment: Or maybe something about using JSON to pass the data to javascript as a PHP array or obejct is not going to be much use to him in js

Comment: Or maybe even just return true or false

Comment: @RiggsFolly it depends on what OP is trying to achieve, but I agree that it should be JSON in most cases.

Comment: @Alexis `return response()->json($data)` will return encoded JSON.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Agreed, they were just suggestions, to avoid the OP coming back with _It still does not work_ again and again

Comment: `VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:` This is issue now!

Comment: Add code from this page to your JS code https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token